# Seeding objects in Guice custom scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, command-line-interface, guice

In a CLI application I have implemented my own custom scope, named `@ImporterScope`. The scope is used with instances of classes that do a standard import job. For example, a `UserImporter` will import a `User` model (representing the XML), a `ScheduleImporter` will import a `Schedule`, etc.

Using Guice, how can I inject instances of objects into the scope? Implementation aside, my goal is to be able to `@Inject` a `Schedule` and/or a `User` *everywhere* in the scope and get a specific instance.

Comment: You are implementing the scope, right?  So you have the ultimate control over how seeding works.  If you want to return particular instances just do it.